# Can't select textbox on website

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a strange problem on http://cooldeal.se. The problem is that textboxes on the page can't bee activated/selected with a mouseclick. The problem appears in some browsers (Opera and Firefox) while in Internet Explorer it works fine. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I tried it and removed the button-wrapper class in chrome, and then i was able to selec the textboxes

Comment: please post your aspx/html and css button_wrapper is using I believe webkit-appearance: textfield; is causing the problem

Answer (score 4):

It's a z-index issue that can be solved by adding a position value to the inputs. Add position: relative; to the inputs and your z-index values will then work.

Comment: This was the answer for me. Just added `style="position: relative;"` and voila! This should have been marked as the answer.